# JavaFX: Wrapping text in ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to build a text editor. I'm using a ListView for storing comments. I want the string to be wrapped automatically without me having to scroll through it horizontally so that long string doesn't have to be scrolled so much.
Please suggest a way to wrap the string in the ListView.

EDIT 1: 
My ListView is initialized from FXML
EDIT 2: 
I could finally get the initialize working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to override the default cell, with your own custom cell whose width is the width of the `List` and also allows text to wrap. The implementation is based on the fact that `Cell`s are [`Labled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html)

```
list.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<DataModel>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item==null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null); 
                    // other stuff to do...

                }else{

                    // set the width's
                    setMinWidth(param.getWidth());
                    setMaxWidth(param.getWidth());
                    setPrefWidth(param.getWidth());

                    // allow wrapping
                    setWrapText(true);

                    setText(item.toString());


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to JavaFX. Where do I write your implementation? Also my ListView contains an observable list of objects of specific class. It doesn't just hold string objects.

Comment: copy- paste the code in your `initialize()` method by implementing `Initializable` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) and replace `DataModel` in the code with the type of values in your `List`. I suggest that you go through this article for more info (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm).

Comment: Please check my edit and suggest me how to proceed. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: oh i made a mistake in my `if statement`, have a look at it and also put the code in initialize() not in an action handler

Comment: I've made a public void initilize() method and copied your code. My start method in main is actually loading another fxml file. I'm adding the initialize method in my controller class. I'm getting the following errors: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                         at textEditor.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:52)

Comment: did you refer to the previous comment and make  changes in the if statement? This change `if (empty || item==null) {`

Comment: Yes I did make changes and put it in initialize() method.

Comment: Got the initialize working (please check edit), But the objects loaded in the ListView are displaying weird strings. Please help!

Comment: in the `setText()` method, put whatever string that needs to be displayed. For Example if theres a method called `AssociatedItem.getComment()` then do `setText(item.getComment())`

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help, I actually did that before reading your comment. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'd suggest that you open this up as another question, provide an [mcve] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as this question was intended to address a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I've resolved it by using mouseClick handle event.